# Trying to write a little text game

Tags: java, text, applet

Hey guys I am trying to write a little text game in my free time and I have started with this code.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class game extends Applet{
public void paint (Graphics g){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?:\t");
    String x = input.nextLine();
    g.drawString("Hello, " + x, 50, 25);
}
}
```

What I want to do is have the applet open right away and then have it ask the questions from within the applet.  Also I want the user to be able to input the questions to the applet.  Any quick way to be able to do this?

Comment: Hmm, a console app in an applet...

Comment: where's the java applet going to live? a webpage?

Comment: just on the screen for now. It just opens a window.  Not looking for optimization

Comment: If you want to use a GUI, look to a free floating frame (a Swing `JFrame`).  It is (a lot) simpler than developing an applet, and can be launched from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest solution for a little game is to work in a console, from a runnable class with a main function.
You will then be able to read and display from the console.

You can even have a look at JCurse or other libraries to have a cooler text design (color,...)

If you nevertheless want to work in an applet, then I think you will have to construct a AWT [edit: AWT, not SWT, that was a mistake!] text area control from which to read inputs and send results.

Anyway enjoy yourself designing your game :)

Comment: Thanks man.  I have been programming a text based game in the console for a looooong time.  I want to put it in an applet now.  You said a SWT text area would be best.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I've never seen an applet using SWT (and I've seen a lot of applets).  Can you link to one?

Comment: oops did I say SWT? AWT! sorry

Comment: Josh : have a look at this example, better than explaining I think. http://www.java-forums.org/java-applets/33837-java-number-guessing-game.html